# Nesting shortcodes in Wordpress results in the inner shortcode not printing out at all

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I've installed the _s theme and have barely begun to work on it.

I am trying to nest a shortcode named "`b`" inside a shortcode named "`cb.`" Here's my code (from the `functions.php` file):

```
// Short Code
function box_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  extract(
      shortcode_atts(array(
          's' => '1'
          ), $atts));

  if($s == '1') { $box_classes = 'c1_4 aside'; }
  if($s == '2') { $box_classes = 'c2_4 main'; }
  if($s == '3') { $box_classes = 'c3_4'; }
  if($s == '4') { $box_classes = 'c4_4'; }

  return '<section class="' . $box_classes . '">' . $content . '</section>';
}
add_shortcode( 'b', 'box_shortcode' );

function contentblock_shortcode( $content = null ) {
  return '<div class="inner">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'cb', 'contentblock_shortcode' );

add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode');
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how you're using your shortcodes?

Answer (score 2):

```
add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode');
```

is not needed.

your both should take atts and content as attributes and your OUTER (not inner) function should have a `do_shortcode` inside it. Final code should be something like:

```
function box_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  extract(
      shortcode_atts(array(
          's' => '1'
          ), $atts));

  if($s == '1') { $box_classes = 'c1_4 aside'; }
  if($s == '2') { $box_classes = 'c2_4 main'; }
  if($s == '3') { $box_classes = 'c3_4'; }
  if($s == '4') { $box_classes = 'c4_4'; }

  return '<section class="' . $box_classes . '">' . $content . '</section>';
}
add_shortcode( 'b', 'box_shortcode' );

function contentblock_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  return '<div class="inner">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'cb', 'contentblock_shortcode' );
```

If you will use your shortcodes as `[cb][b]content[/b][/cb]`
If you'd like to use them the other way around, move `do_shortcode($content)` to the function `box_shortcode( $atts, $content = null )`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is your `contentblock_shortcode` function takes `$content` as its first argument whereas it should take `$atts` first. Changing it to `function contentblock_shortcode($atts, $content = null)` should allow the inner `do_shortcode` to pass only the content on to the `do_shortcode` method within the inner section.